# Flutter: shrink images to fit into row while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to display two images side by side with a bit of text above and below. The layout has to work in portrait and landscape mode. The images are loaded from the network and I don't know their dimensions, although I do know the aspect ratio (3:4) and orientation (portrait).

The current solution works well in portrait mode but totally fails in landscape. Here the middle section with the two images is scaled down to fit the width which ends up with images that are too high for the space available.

```
[...]
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Text 1', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline),
        IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TrimmedImage(left.src, () => _advanceRight()),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TrimmedImage(right.src, () => _advanceLeft()),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Text('Text 2, possibly lines and lines and lines and lines and lines anlines and lines of stuff.',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
} 
[...]

class TrimmedImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String src;
  final onTap;

  TrimmedImage(src, this.onTap);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 3.0 / 4.0,
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              border: new Border.all(
                color: Colors.grey,
                width: 2.0,
              ),
              borderRadius:
              new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: onTap,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  errorWidget: Icon(Icons.broken_image),
                  imageUrl: src ?? '',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

In Landscape mode I'd like the images to be scaled down (while keeping the aspect ratio) to fit the height of the available space, rather than the width.

[image: images too large in landscape mode]

Portrait mode currently looks good on a big screen but I suspect it'd also fail if the screen were too small to fit the height of all 3 components.

[image: portrait mode looks good]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own layout with a CustomMultiChildLayout and, specifically, a MultiChildLayoutDelegate.  The Flutter Shrine demo is a good example: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/shrine/shrine_home.dart.  See the _Heading and _HeadingLayout classes.